# Error in React form re-rendering using a state variable

Tags: javascript, reactjs, forms

```
const [ usernameBox , setUsernameBox ] = useState(false);

return(
    {
        usernameBox ?
            <>
                 <div style={{ fontSize:"25px" }}>{"Sign up with Security"}</div>
                 <TileInput placeholder={"Enter Password"} />
                 <TileButton value={"Confirm"} />
            </>
        :<>
                 <div style={{ fontSize:"25px" }}>{ ("Sign up"}</div>
                 <TileInput placeholder={"Enter username"} />
                 <TileButton value={"Continue"} onClick={ () => setUsernameBox(true) } />
            </>
    }
);
```

Here there are two block of forms. when usernameBlock is false the 2nd block(username section) is rendered. when user enter a input  and click on button usernameBlock's value changes to true. So , 1st block(password section) is rendered. NO problem in that.  **and  are same as normal input and button which is Styled and kept as another component. So no problem related to that**

The problem is when I enter name in input of username section and click button , the **same** name is appearing in the input of password section ? how to make it empty input to allow user to submit their password

Comment: What is `TileInput`? Where is it getting its value from? Using controlled inputs will probably solve this.

Comment: not an answer to your question but on those lines - https://codesandbox.io/s/flamboyant-yonath-js2xl?file=/src/App.js

Answer (score 0):

You should make inputs controlled by keeping value in your component state. And on change of input set local state.
Something like this.

```js
const [ usernameBox , setUsernameBox ] = useState(false);
const [ name , setName ] = useState("");
const [ password , setPassword ] = useState("");



return(
    {
        usernameBox ?
            <>
                 <div style={{ fontSize:"25px" }}>{"Sign up with Security"}</div>
                 <input placeholder={"Enter Password"} value={password} onChnage={(e)=> setPassword(e.target.value)}/>
                 <Button value={"Confirm"} />
            </>
        :<>
                 <div style={{ fontSize:"25px" }}>{ ("Sign up"}</div>
                 <input placeholder={"Enter username"} value={name} onChnage={(e)=> setName(e.target.value)}/> />
                 <Button value={"Continue"} onClick={ () => setUsernameBox(true) } />
            </>
    }
);
```